# Reveal.js and plotly - exporting to pdf?

Tags: plotly, reveal.js

I'm using reveal js to display some locally hosted plotly charts using iframe.

This works fine other than ability to export to pdf. When I go to `http://localhost:138/presentations/pres1/?print-pdf`  ([as described here](https://revealjs.com/pdf-export/)),  I am able to export the text, but the plotly charts don't appear. I assume this is due to the plotly library not loading.

**Is there a way of loading the local html file so that it can be exported to pdf?**

I'm using the following in my slides:

```
#### Slide with iframe

<iframe data-src="http://localhost:138/html/localpage.html" width="900" height="500" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="yes" style="border:0px solid #666; margin-bottom:5px; max-width: 600%;" allowfullscreen=true></iframe>
```

I'm saving the plotly chart [using export interactive html](https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late for you, but I'll still answer for future searchers of the same problem :-)

This is due to the lazy-loading of iframes. When you set the data-preload attribute to the iframe it should appear in the print version.

I described my problem here, maybe we'll be able to add an automated solution as well:
https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/2795#issue-714101762

Comment: Could you elaborate slightly on how to set the data-preload attribute? Thanks!

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke like this: `<iframe data-src="https://hakim.se" data-preload></iframe>`as described in https://revealjs.com/media/#lazy-loading-iframes