# reveal.js with plotly.js and chart.js export pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, chart.js, reveal.js, plotly.js

I am using `reveal.js` for my presentation. The presentation has some animated plots using `plotly.js` and `chart.js`. For performance reasons, I used addEventListner so that the animations run only when I reach to that slide. For example:

```
Reveal.addEventListener("slide2", function () {
 // plot function here
}
```

When I export the slides to pdf using `?print-pdf`, all the canvas elements are rendered blank. Is there a way to get around this so that the printed pdf contains at least the initial or final frame or any frame of these animated plots?

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043116/reveal-js-and-plotly-exporting-to-pdf) but that question was related to `export-pdf` on `iframe` elements. The suggested answer there to disable lazy-loading by using `data-preload` does not work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways, if you create your chart after you call the print pdf function you can set the `animation` option to `false` so the chart doesnt animate and shows instantly, and set it to `true` for normal. The other way you can go is by going into your chart variable and then set the `animation` to false and update it.

```js
let animate = false; // Option 1, set this variable to the correct value before creating the chart

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    animation: animate
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);

// Option 2, update the animation mode on the fly
const switchMode = () => {
  chart.options.animation = !chart.options.animation;
}
// Option 2 if you want to make sure at all times it is false for printing
const setAniFalse = () => {
  chart.options.animation = false;
}
// Option 2 if you want to make sure at all times it is true for showing in presentation
const setAniTrue = () => {
  chart.options.animation = true;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
  <button onClick="switchMode()">
      Switch ani mode
    </button>
</body>
```